# Geolocation search with Weaviate

Tags: weaviate

I am running the geolocation search with weaviate based on their provided [example](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/api/graphql/filters#geocoordinates-filter).

However, I dont seem to be able to run the example with pseudo inputs. Can someone provide me a minimal working example ?

Here is my schema:

```
{
    "class": "RealEstate",
    "description": "Real estates up for rental or purchase.", 
    "moduleConfig": {
        "text2vec-transformers": {
            "vectorizeClassName": false
        }
    },
    "properties": [
        {
            "dataType": ["text"],
            "description": "A description of the property e.g. number of bathrooms, type of heating etc.",
            "name": "description"
        },

        {
            "dataType": ["geoCoordinates"],
            "description": "The geocoordinate corresponding to the address",
            "name": "coordinates"
        }
 

    ],

    "invertedIndexConfig": {                  
    "stopwords": { 
        "preset": "en"                                
    },
    "indexTimestamps": false,                
    "indexNullState": false,                 
    "indexPropertyLength": false           
  },
    "vectorizer": "text2vec-transformers"
}
```

Here is a dummy object I ingest:

```
dummy_realestate = {
    "description": "Dummy house",
    "coordinates": {"latitude": 52.366667, "longitude": 4.9},
}
```

Here is the query:

```
query = """
{
Get {
    RealEstate(where: {
    path: ["coordinate"]
    operator: WithinGeoRange
    valueGeoRange: {
        geoCoordinates: {
        latitude: 52.5200
        longitude: 13.4050
        }
        distance: {
        max: 200
        }
    }
    }) {
    description
    coordinate {
        latitude
        longitude
                }
        }
    }
}
"""

query_result = client.query.raw(query)
```

Finally, here is the error message after querying:

explorer: list class: search: object search at index realestate: shard realestate_qCQXCg5EoW8I: data type "geoCoordinates" not supported yet in standalone mode, see https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/more-resources/architecture.html#standalone-mode-in-022x for details

I am running *semitechnologies/weaviate:1.18.0* image with docker-compose and using Python for querying.

Comment: It is not clear (to me) which part of running the example is problematic. The code itself is fine, you can click on the "Try out this GraphQL example in the Weaviate Console" link below the example snippet you linked to verify. So is your issue with setting up a client, or modifying the query? What do you mean with "pseudo inputs"? Which programming language/workflow do you use for querying the database?

Comment: @Marijn, sorry I didn't want to spam the post but I guess the info is crucial. I have edited the post with more info now. My main issue is I can't run the sample query on my setup. I am using python for querying.